# How to save file in folder and show ?Jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr-hub

I'm developing a simple  `chatroom` in which different user join chatroom and chat with each others.It working fine but i also want that users  `share` pics or any other file with each other.How can i `save` file and show file .

`How can i get input file and save in folder and show in divchatwindow as well.`

**ASPX CODE :**
     
    
         Chat Room

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <div id="divLogin" class="login">
        <div>
            Your Name:<br />
        <input id="txtNickName" type="text" class="textBox" />
        </div>
        <div id="divButton">
            <input id="btnStartChat" type="button" class="submitButton" value="Start Chat" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="divChat" class="chatRoom">
        <div class="title">
            Welcome to Chat Room [<span id='spanUser'></span>]

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="divChatWindow" class="chatWindow">
            </div>
            <div id="divusers" class="users">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="messageBar">
            <input class="textbox" type="text" id="txtMessage" />
            <input id="btnSendMsg" type="button" value="Send" class="submitButton" />
           <input type ="file" id="uploadfile" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
    <input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {

            var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();
            if (msg.length > 0) {

                var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
                chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg);
                $("#txtMessage").val('');
            }
        });
       function AddMessage(userName, message) {
        $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + userName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');

        var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
    }
   </script>
```

**chatHub.cs Class**

```
  public void SendMessageToAll(string userName, string message)
    {
        // store last 100 messages in cache
        AddMessageinCache(userName, message);

        // Broad cast message
        Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message);

    }
  private void AddMessageinCache(string userName, string message)
    {
    CurrentMessage.Add(new MessageDetail { UserName = userName, Message = message });

        if (CurrentMessage.Count > 100)
            CurrentMessage.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

MessageDetail.cs

```
 public class MessageDetail
 {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: You can save files on the server first then send the link to the user for download.

Comment: Yes I can do this,,but when i do this using `send button` click event then i save file in folder ,but page is reloaded/refreshed again,and again ask for username etc.I do this on another button `filesend` `protected void sendbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileupload.HasFile && fileupload.FileContent.Length > 0)
            {
                string filename = fileupload.FileName.ToString();
                fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/new/" + filename));
            }
        }`

Comment: You have to use ajax to prevent page reload. You can use jQuery AJAX method for this - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/